# Can't reach EOF with fscanf loop

Tags: c, file, eof, do-while

Helo, as I continue with my HW project, i am stucked in reading EOF, given this loop, it's stucked forever and obviously, input never gets value of EOF, what am I doing wrong?

```
int main ()
{
FILE *ffil;
char input;
ffil=fopen("a.csv","r");
printf("error0");
do
{
    fscanf("%c",&input);
}while(input!=EOF);
fclose(ffil);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: check return value of scanf, also you use fscanf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scanf` doesn't work that way.  Also, `EOF` does not fit in a `char`.  If you want to read character by character until `EOF`, do it the idiomatic way:

```
int input;  /* int, not char! */

while ( (input = getchar()) != EOF )
{
    /* do stuff with 'input' here. */
}
```

If you really want to use `scanf`, you can.  It returns the number of values successfully converted, so you could use that instead of testing for `EOF`:

```
char input;  /* char, not int! */

while ( scanf("%c", &input) == 1 )  /* loop while scanf succeeds */
{
    /* do stuff with 'input' here */
}
```

Both of those read from `stdin`, but it appears your test really wants to read from `ffil`.  If that's the case (it wasn't clear from your question), modify the above examples as follows:

```
int input;  /* int, not char! */

while ( (input = fgetc(ffil)) != EOF )
{
    /* do stuff with 'input' here. */
}
```

or

```
char input;  /* char, not int! */

while ( fscanf(ffil, "%c", &input) == 1 )  /* loop while scanf succeeds */
{
    /* do stuff with 'input' here */
}
```

Comment: Yes, i want to read from ffil using fscanf, not scanf, my bad, sorry and actually your idea to read chars as int is not a bad one, the only thing why i will be using this is to see, if there exists anoter line with more data, or there is an EOF, so all i am testing is, if fscanf will give me '/n' or EOF value :-)
So thanks, I will work with int input.

Comment: If you use `fgetc()`, you can also use `ungetc()` if you just need to peek at the next character without consuming it.  You can `unget` one character safely.